# Get grand total minus discounts

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, totals

I use an extension to calculate shipping costs based on distance. There is a free shipping function which is applied when `getBaseSubtotalInclTax()` is higher than X. I need the total for all products minus discounts. How do I get it?

Answer (score 3):

`$quote->getBaseSubTotal()` and `$quote->getBaseSubTotalInclTax()` already give you the subtotal (i.e. total of all products) without discounts.

If you need the **grand total** (with shipping and other additional costs), **except** discounts, you can try to subtract it:

```
$quote->getBaseGrandTotal() - $quote->getTotals()['discount']->getValue()
```